# change object get from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I’d like to change object get from NSUserDefaults.
But when executing following code, the app crash with error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object’
```

I have this code.

```
NSUserDefaults* pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
data = [[pref objectForKey:@"Data"] mutableCopy];

for (NSArray* array in data) { //make object mutable
        [array mutableCopy];
        for (NSDictionary* dic in array) {
            [dic mutableCopy];
        }
    }

[data[0][1] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"isChecked"]; //for example

[pref setObject: data forKey: @"Data"];
[pref synchronize];
```

The structure of data:

```
NSMutableArray* arr1 = [@[[@{@"name":@"abc", @"isChecked":@"YES"} mutableCopy], [@{@"name":@"def", @"isChecked":@"NO"} mutableCopy]] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray* arr2 = [@[[@{@"name":@"ghi", @"isChecked":@"NO"} mutableCopy], [@{@"name":@"jkl", @"isChecked":@"YES"} mutableCopy]] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray* data = [@[arr1, arr2] mutableCopy];
[userDefaults setObject: data forKey: @"Data"];
```

How do I fix it to change object in `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` get from `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea - the objects returned from `NSUserDefaults` are immutable, and you need to use `mutableCopy` to get a mutable copy.  However, your implementation is flawed.

`mutableCopy` returns a new, mutable copy of the object.  It does not make the existing object mutable.  You are simply ignoring the mutable copy that you are creating.

As you want to mutate the data in your arrays, you can't use enumeration or you will get an error that the object was mutated while enumerating, so you will need to access the arrays by index -

```
NSUserDefaults* pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray* data = [[pref objectForKey:@"Data"] mutableCopy]; 

for (int i=0;i<data.count;i++) { 
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [data[i] mutableCopy];
    for (int j=0;j<mArray.count;j++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary=[mArray[j] mutableCopy];
        mDictionary[@"SomeKey"]=@"SomeValue";
        mArray[j]=mDictionary;
    }
    data[i]=mArray;
}

[userDefaults setObject: data forKey: @"Data"];
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP does have the right idea.  His idea is to use `NSUserDefaults` as a general purpose data-storage mechanism, accessible anywhere within his app.  This isn't what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

`[array mutableCopy]` will create a mutable copy of the array and **returns** it. You are not assigning it to the variable again. This will resolve your issue i guess.

```
array = [array mutableCopy];
```

similarly

```
dic = [dic mutableCopy];
```